# Adding values to the controller action manually

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a model class that is below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace MyForms.Models
{
    public class Master
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string ModuleName { get; set; }
        public int CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public int ModifyBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime ModifyDate { get; set; }
        public Boolean IsActive { get; set; }
        public Boolean IsDeleted { get; set; }

        //  public virtual ICollection<MasterModule> MasterModules { get; set; }
    }
```

Here in this code I am passing the values through views(textboxes). What are my expections

1. Module Name is entered through text box and when submit button is clicked
2. CreatedBy contains the ID of the person who create the module(e.g 1. admin 2. manager)
3. Created date is automatically added as current Date when submit is clicked
4. ModifyBy contains the ID of the person who modify (edit) the module(e.g 1. admin 2. manager)
5. ModifyDate is the curent date when the module is edited
6. when the module is created is activated always sets to be true.

2 to 6 are settled with coding. Now I want to know how can I handle each situation separetaly.

**Currently I am adding all the values manually, I mean through the input box and checkboxes**

```
namespace MyForms.Controllers
{
    public class MasterController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Master/
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            using (MyFormDemoContext context = new MyFormDemoContext()) 
            {
                return View(context.MasterForms.ToList());
            }

            //  return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Master master)
        {
            try
            {
                using (MyFormDemoContext context = new MyFormDemoContext()) 
                {
                    context.MasterForms.Add(master);
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please phrase your question correctly. I guess you are asking you are not able to post data from your view to POST method of Create. If my guess is correct, you need to show us your View code.

Comment: Are you asking how to only send the `ModuleName` property, or that none of the data makes it from the page to the action?

Comment: 1.Module name Sended by text box
2.CreatedDate will be send when the module name is entered, on the view there is only one text box that is for the ModuleName . rest of the data will be conditionaly based liked. when the entry is modified the modifiedDate will be passed as the current date of system automaticaly not manually by me

Comment: When i add the module name the IsActive property set as true automaticly

Comment: i update the code @HaBo .. please help me if u can

Comment: If you don't have html input controls for `CreatedBy`, `CreatedDate` etc, they are not going to be sent to the controller. Why not just set them in the post method e.g. `master.CreatedDate = DateTime.Today; master.IsActive  = true;` etc.

Comment: yes done @StephenMuecke .......

Comment: As @HaBo has already mentioned, we really need to see your View code to gauge what is going on. Exactly which one of your steps numbered above are you having issue with?